# Is water acidic enough for an redox reaction involving H+?

Tags: electrochemistry, aqueous-solution

If you stored $\ce{Pb(NO3)2(aq)}$ in a $\ce{Cu(s)}$ container, would any reaction occur? Lead(II) ions will not react spontaneously with the copper solid as the $E^0_\mathrm{net}$ of the reaction would be negative. However, the $E^0_\mathrm{net}$ of the reaction between nitrate ions and copper solid is positive. The reduction reaction for nitrate ions is
$$\ce{2 NO3- (aq) + 4 H+(aq) + 2 e- -> N2O4(g) + 2 H2O(l)}\qquad{E^0=\mathrm{+0.80\ V}}$$

As is obvious, the reaction requires not only nitrate but hydrogen ions. However, water (the solvent) does have hydrogen/hydronium ions. Would this be enough to furnish the reaction? If not, why?

Comment: "Hydronium ion" and "$\ce{H^+}(\mathrm{aq})$" refer to pretty much exactly the same thing.

Comment: @hBy2Py I know. That’s the underlying assumption of my question. Perhaps I should rephrase: "would the *hydrogen ions* in water be enough to furnish the reaction?"

Comment: Gotcha. My guess is "Yes," but I'm not sure enough to put an answer down on it.

Comment: You are overgeneralizing. Yes, water contains enough $\ce{H+}$ for _some_ redox reactions; throw a little sodium in it and you will see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the reaction would be spontaneous at standard conditions.  However standard conditions for electrochemistry are at pH 0, i.e. an $[\ce{H+}]$ concentration of 1 molar.

Solutions of lead nitrate by themselves are not going to give you pH 0.  Apparently very very concentrated lead nitrate solutions will reach pH 3 or 4, due to the weakly acidic nature of hydrated lead ions.

The electrochemical potential of the reaction you are interested in at pH 3 can be calculated from the standard (i.e. pH 0) potential via the Nernst equation.

$$E_\mathrm{cathode} = E_0\;– \frac{RT}{nF}\ln{Q}$$

Here, $Q$ is the "half"-reaction quotient, given by
$$ Q = \frac{\mathrm{p}_{\ce{N2O4}}}{[\ce{NO3-}]^2[\ce{H+}]^4}$$ Now assume that nitrate concentration and the partial pressure of dinitrogen tetroxide are in their standard states.

If you go through the math (see examples [here](https://socratic.org/questions/how-does-ph-affect-the-nernst-equation) or [here](http://www.chem1.com/acad/webtext/elchem/ec5.html)), then you will see that there is a 118 millivolt-per-decade decrease in the potential, i.e. every increase in the pH by 1 unit decreases the potential by 118 mV.  So already at pH 3 the reaction will no longer be favorable.

Copper is unstable to concentrated nitric acid, but the acid needs to be concentrated.  Dilute acids cannot oxidize copper so easily.

Comment: Thanks! I’ve done some calculations and I understand it fully now. However, did you make a mistake with the expression for Q? Doesn’t the Nernst equation apply for the entire cell? Wouldn’t Q need to have [$\ce{Cu^2+}$]?

Comment: Yeah apologies my answer was confusing.  You can write Nernst equations for an entire cell, or for each half-cell separately.  The $Q$ I wrote was for the half-reaction you put in the OP, but the Nernst equation is mislabeled as "$E_{cell}$".  It should really say $E_{cathode}$.  I'll edit to correct.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your redox reaction. For example, if you add permanganate to a neutral solution containing e.g. sulphite, you will observe a redox reaction in which manganese(IV) oxide is created. If you do your redox caluculations, you will observe the following:

$$\begin{align}\tag{red}\ce{MnO4- + 3 e- + 4 H+ &-> MnO2 + 2 H2O}& | \cdot 2\\
\tag{ox}\ce{SO3^2- + H2O & -> SO4^2- + 2 e- + 2 H+} & | \cdot 3\\
\tag{redox}\ce{2 MnO4- + 2 H+ + 3 SO3^2- &-> 2 MnO2 + H2O + 3 SO4^2-}&\end{align}$$

This reaction still consumes protons but proceeds under neutral conditions. (Under acidic conditions, permanganate would reduce to $\ce{Mn^2+}$, und strongly basic conditions it would end up as $\ce{MnO4^2-}$.)